# Powershell SQL Server Agent CmdExec job step multiple line code

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-agent

Why does code like this execute in PowerShell ISE:

```
$var = 'dog';Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance 'servername' -Query "insert into DB.dbo.tbl values ('$($var)')"
```

But not in SQL Server Agent as a CmdExec job step? Despite enclosing it as per usual. I believe it is the multiple queries as individual queries work

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command {$var = 'dog';Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance 'servername' -Query "insert into DB.dbo.tbl values ('$($var)')"}
```

TL;DR;

I have a SQL Server Agent job with a CmdExec step. I wish to assign a variable and then use it in an insert statement.

So far the following insert will work:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance 'servername' -Query 'insert into DB.dbo.tbl values (''cat'')'"
```

This inserts a cat. Now I need a dog, something along the lines of:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "$var = 'dog'; Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance 'servername' -Query ""insert into DB.dbo.tbl values (''$($var)'')"""
```

There are two issues here, the comma terminator which I have used successfully in other jobs to separate commands. The second issue is escaping the double quotes. I understand they are required to process the variable into the string.

I have tried escaping with double quotes as well as one of these `. I've also tried separating the variable declaration into one server agent job step and using the variable in another.

Based on @gvee answer below, I put the code in a script block, which executes perfectly in PowerShell, but not as a SQL Agent CmdExec job step

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command {$var = '''dog'''; Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance 'servername' -Query "insert into DB.dbo.tbl values ($($var))"}
```

Note I had to escape the variable three times, which inserted into the table as 'dog' with the quotes included. I removed the single quotes from the insert statement, however I cannot get this to run in Server Agent as a CmdExec step

Comment: Please don't update your question with answers. Post them as answers instead. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! 3 quotes work for me also! You saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

`-Command` accepts a ScriptBlock, so give this a whirl:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command {
    Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance "servername" -Query "insert into DB.dbo.tbl values ('cat')"
}
```